# Integrating eventkit from GCCalendar to show events from single day

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar

I am implementing the [gccalendar for day calendar view from Github](https://github.com/fraca7/GCCalendar).

The events added as sample are showing on all dates. I have to integrate eventkit to it to add the events. How can I show the events added on that single day?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you have to integrate gccalenadr and the eventkit source logically for displaying the events on the particular dates.

Comment: do you possibly have any examples? I tried the setWeekday method of the NSDateComponent but the event still showed up on all days